# Backup my AWS Parameter Store to an S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-parameter-store

Trying to create a simple solution to backup my AWS parameter store to S3 and most probably trigger it to back up every evening.

Anyone have any ideas or help on how I can get this started?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Parameter Store for (dynamic) runtime data storage or simply for (static) application configuration? Hopefully the latter, in which case your configuration should be coming from some Infrastructure as Code source and that itself is what you would revision control and backup.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a programming language that you are comfortable using, and use the AWS SDK for that language to do the following:

1. Query the parameter store to get the list of parameters.
2. Iterate over the list of parameters, getting the value for each.
3. Then you can take those parameter keys/values and write them out to a file in the format of your choice.
4. Upload the file to your S3 bucket.

You could write this as an AWS Lambda function which runs on a schedule and it would fall within the AWS free tier pricing.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Python code to gather, pull and send to s3 bucket of my choice.

Worked fine.

So im going to put it all into terraform code.

Cheers!